# How to mock router state in ember + jasmine

Tags: javascript, ember.js, jasmine

In my jasmine test suite I want to navigate my router to the right state. Something like this:

```
   describe("The Router", function(){
        beforeEach(function(){
            router = App.Router.create();
            router.transitionTo('foo.bar');
        }
    });
```

but if I do so, I get an `Cannot call method 'disconnectOutlet' of undefined` error. That happens cuz I am calling

```
     bar: Ember.Route.extend({      
        connectOutlets: function(router, context){
          router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('bla', 'blub');
        }
      }),
```

at this router transition. I tried somehow to init my applicationController like

```
applicationController = App.ApplicationController.create();
```

but it doesnt change the error. So how can I mock to be in the right router state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you testing this with jasmine today? Are you going to the browse with each change or trying to run it from the command line with something like jasmine-phantom-node / jasmine-node?

One example might look something like the below. In the setup below I'm testing a view but the same mocking / spying ideas apply to the router example you have above.

```
require('static/script/vendor/filtersortpage.js');
require('static/script/app/person.js');

describe ("PersonApp.PersonView Tests", function(){

  var sut, router, controller;

  beforeEach(function(){
    sut = PersonApp.PersonView.create();
    router = new Object({send:function(){}});
    controller = PersonApp.PersonController.create({});
    controller.set("target", router);
    sut.set("controller", controller);
  });

  it ("does not invoke send on router when username does not exist", function(){
    var event = {'context': {'username':'', 'set': function(){}}};
    var sendSpy = spyOn(router, 'send');
    sut.addPerson(event);
    expect(sendSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith('addPerson', jasmine.any(String));
  });

  it ("invokes send on router with username when exists", function(){
    var event = {'context': {'username':'foo', 'set': function(){}}};
    var sendSpy = spyOn(router, 'send');
    sut.addPerson(event);
    expect(sendSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('addPerson', 'foo');
  });

  it ("does not invoke set context when username does not exist", function(){
    var event = {'context': {'username':'', 'set': function(){}}};
    var setSpy = spyOn(event.context, 'set');
    sut.addPerson(event);
    expect(setSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith('username', jasmine.any(String));
  });

  it ("invokes set context to empty string when username exists", function(){
    var event = {'context': {'username':'foo', 'set': function(){}}};
    var setSpy = spyOn(event.context, 'set');
    sut.addPerson(event);
    expect(setSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('username', '');
  });
});
```

[Here](https://github.com/toranb/ember-django-rest/blob/master/ember/static/script/tests/people.spec.js) is the jasmine test above in a real project if you want to see it with some context

Here is the view under test (to help make sense of the above jasmine tests)

```
PersonApp.PersonView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'person',
  addPerson: function(event) {
    var username = event.context.username;
    if (username) {
      this.get('controller.target').send('addPerson', username);
      event.context.set('username', '');
    }
  }
});
```