# What is the best way to do TDD/BDD for ember.js?

Tags: javascript, tdd, ember.js, bdd, jasmine

Found one approach with Jasmine: [Ember.js TDD – how to test your ember views](http://shairez.com/2012/07/ember-js-tdd-how-to-test-your-ember-views/)

Has anyone used this approach? Are there any other/better ways of doing TDD/BDD for Ember?

Comment: To see a simple example showing how you might unit test an ember view using jasmine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688650/how-to-mock-router-state-in-ember-jasmine/13706080#13706080

Comment: Maybe you should also look into Ember.js repo and see how their tests are done

Comment: How is Ember, Jasmine, TDD/BDD and best practices not a good fit for SO?